# How to create a material design style depth score in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, icon, google-material-design

According to Material Design [guidelines for Icons](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons)

> Score
>
> Scored material elements have the illusion of depth without losing
>   their geometric form. Scores should be centered on symmetrical shapes.

It looks like this:
[image: score Material Design]

How can I make a score like this in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a rectangle, filled with grey, over the area to be dark. Set the blend mode to `Multiply`.

[image]

Add a slight `Outer Glow` layer style to the rectangle to create the white highlight at the edge.

[image]

Then under the **Blending Options** tick the item titled `Layer Mask Hides Effects`

[image]

Command/Ctrl click the outer shape of the desired object to create a selection, then click the `New Mask` button at the bottom of the Layers Panel to add a **Layer Mask** to the rectangle.

[image]

Reduce the `Opacity` of the rectangle layer to your liking.

[image]

This is just one method. There are others.